# What does/can fake: do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I've inherited this code and I'm aware that this is creating a stub for fake api calls. I don't understand how it is working. Can it return only JSON? Can I set a response to simply a 200 success? Is there any documentation on this?

```
class GuessTransaction < ActiveRestClient::Base
  request_body_type :json

  get :all, '/transaction', fake: [{last_name:"Durdan", first_name:"Tyler"}]
  get :find, '/transaction/:id', fake: {id: "1", first_name:"Tyler", last_name: "Durdan"}
  post :create, '/transaction', fake:->(request) { {id: 12345 } }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Source](https://github.com/whichdigital/active-rest-client/blob/master/lib/active_rest_client/request.rb#L146) for `active-rest-client`.

**Excerpt**

```
        return handle_response(
          OpenStruct.new(
            status:200, 
            body:fake, 
            response_headers:{
              "X-ARC-Faked-Response" => "true", 
               "Content-Type" => content_type
            }
           )
         )
```

It appears it will always respond with `200` so you can just do something like `fake:{}`

This will respond with `200` and an empty `body` for the response.

Even `fake: true` should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation for [`active-rest-client`](https://github.com/whichdigital/active-rest-client)
you can find this:

> [Faking Calls](https://github.com/whichdigital/active-rest-client#faking-calls)
>
> There are times when an API hasn't been developed yet, so you want to
>   fake the API call response. To do this, **you can simply pass a fake
>   option** when mapping the call containing the response.

```
class Person < ActiveRestClient::Base
  get :all, '/people', fake: [{first_name:"Johnny"}, {first_name:"Bob"}]
end
```

> You may want to run a proc when faking data (to put information from
>   the parameters in to the response or return different responses
>   depending on the parameters). **To do this just pass a proc to :fake**:

```
class Person < ActiveRestClient::Base
  get :all, '/people', fake: ->(request) { {result: request.get_params[:id]} }
end
```

Comment: Thank you! [link](https://github.com/whichdigital/active-rest-client) is exactly what I was looking for.